# How to use LISTAGG and WHERE together

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, listagg

So I am trying to use a `LISTAGG` function while using a `WHERE` statement. 
What I want to do is search by the `WHERE` statement and the `LISTAGG` returns a list with in relations to other columns.

In other words, when I use the `WHERE` statement with `LISTAGG`, I only get the value that I'm searching for. The other values associated with the other columns don't show up.

My script is kind of like this:

```
WITH TEST AS 
  (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         LOCATION,
         ID,
         LISTAGG (TOMATOCOUNT, ', ') 
             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TOMATOCOUNT) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY LOCATION, ID) TOMATOTYPES,

  FROM TOMATOLAND
  )

SELECT
*
FROM TEST
WHERE (:TOMATOTYPE = TOMATO
    OR :TOMATOTYPE IS NULL)
```

Comment: Meant to be WITH TEST AS

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

Filter on the result of `LISTAGG` strikes me as a bit backwords. Generally, if you're going to aggregate several items into a list, you're doing it at the last minute, for display purposes. ideally you would filter prior to the aggregation.

The following will return one row for each `location`/`ID` that contains the specified `tomatotype`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       location,
       id,
       LISTAGG (tomatotype, ', ')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tomatocount)
           OVER (PARTITION BY location, id)
           tomatotypes
FROM   tomatoland
WHERE  (location, id) IN (SELECT location, id
                          FROM   tomatoland
                          WHERE  :tomatotype = tomatotype)
       OR  :tomatotype IS NULL
```

Comment: I think this would be faster than gordon's answer but I'd like the `or null` in the main where statement -- eg `WHERE :tomatotype IS NULL OR (location, id) IN (SELECT location, id FROM   tomatoland WHERE  :tomatotype = tomatotype)` seems the optimizer would do a better job there.

Comment: Ah, thank you both for your help, it's done the trick for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
WITH TEST AS (
      SELECT LOCATION, ID,
             LISTAGG(TOMATOTYPE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TOMATOCOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY LOCATION, ID) as TOMATOTYPES
      FROM TOMATOLAND
     )
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE ', ' || :TOMATOTYPE || ', ' LIKE '%,' || TOMATOTYPES || ', %' OR
      :TOMATOTYPE IS NULL
```